# How to filter measure names in Tableau?

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I was curious if anyone knew how to filter measure names so when a value is selected, only certain measure names appear. For example:

```
When 'Finance' is selected,
Show Profit, Sales, Revenue

When 'Investment' is selected
Show Stock Price, # of shares
```

Quick example of what I'm trying to accomplish. I know how to do this if you want to change one measure name, but not sure how to do it with multiple measure names. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could create calculated fields(Analysis->Calculated Field) for each measure which feature IF statements. Like:

Calculate Field 1

```
IF [Type of Dimension] = 'Finance' THEN [Profit] ELSE NULL END
```

Calculate Field 2

```
IF [Type of Dimension] = 'Finance' THEN [Revenue] ELSE NULL END
```

Calculate Field 3

```
IF [Type of Dimension] = 'Investment' THEN [No of Shares] ELSE NULL END
```

Then drag all these calculated fields into your row shelf and your 'Type of Dimension' into your column shelf.

Right click on your dimension and select filter, then selecting your needed dimension should leave only the measures you wanted.

There's probably a smarter way but this is one way to do it, be it not very elegant.

See this for further info:
https://community.tableau.com/thread/118957